# Linq Foreign Key Select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two tables with a one (Articles) to many (Details) relationship. Details may not contain any data for the particular Article entry.

Articles: Id, Title, Numb (PK), Name

Details: Id (PK), Person, Numb (FK), Name

In the Entity Framework, there are the appropriate Navigation properties and it shows the correct One:Many relationship.

What I want to do is get all Articles that match the end user's query (by 'Name') as well as all, if any, data from the Details table (Id, Person, Numb, Name).

What I'm stuck on is right now I can query Articles just fine (`var article = db.Articles.Where(b => b.Name.Equals(name));`), but while the result does include a HashSet for Details.Numb on each row of Articles, there is no data in that HashSet. There are appropriate corresponding entries in the database for Article.Numb => Details.Numb.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is two ways to achieve this.

1. Enable Lazy Loading.
2. Call `Include` method as other answers says.

**Using Lazy Loading** see [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx) for more detail.

```
    db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

**Using Include method**

```
    var article = db.db.Articles.Include("Details").Where(b => b.Name.Equals(name))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is it possible to use Include without FirstOrDefault? Multiple entries are expected to be returned.

Comment: It looks like there may just be something wrong with the relationship (?). When I break in the debugger and examine db.Articles results view, there are no results for Details on any result that has a valid FK in Details.

Comment: Using LINQPad, I was able to successfully query (using from a in Articles where a.Name.Equals("value") select a) the database and return results. In this case, it returned 3 results from Articles, and then one of those results had an EntitySet<Details> with two results. This is ideally how I would like the data to be displayed. Using the exact same query in my Web API app, I still see Article.Detail.Count == 0 in the same result that returned an EntitySet via LINQPad.

Comment: Alright, before posting this as a resolution, I'd like to see if there is a cleaner way to do this, as this yields the desired result. 'from a in db.Articles.Where(a => a.Name.Equals("value")).Select(a => new {a.Title,a.Numb,a.Name}) select a;. The output provides each line item, and an array of Details (with all fields from the Details table) for items (instead of creating a one-to-one output of Articles to Details).

Comment: @TrevorSeward Did include not work in your scenario. your above query would not work if lazy loading is not enabled else it would have worked. Although lazy loading would do the work I would always prefer to go with Include.

Comment: Correct, Include() did not work (and using FirstOrDefault won't work for this solution as I expect >1 result). Lazy Loading is not enabled on the EF Model.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Can you also post both of your models (Articles and Details) to the question?.

Comment: I have a similar problem, and I can not use Include([foreign_key_column_name]) since I used entity framework code first. The foreign keys were automatically generated and are only visible n the database table column, not in the model class. Can someone help me? I posted a question here, but DTO is still confusing me `https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d49772c9-c108-4418-b782-e231f60b6ffc/foreign-id-attribute-cannot-be-accessed-in-linq-query-for-an-object-of-a-class-that-has-a-list-of?forum=csharpgeneral`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell EF to include the details in the result set after the query is executed (and connection closes):

```
var article = db.Articles
    .Include("Details")
    .Where(b => b.Name.Equals(name))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I have a similar problem to the question. Using `include()` won't work since the foreign key was generated with EF Code First. If I include the foreign key in the `include`, it will not find anything because my model does not have a column called `[foreign key column name]`. Here's my original question: `https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d49772c9-c108-4418-b782-e231f60b6ffc/foreign-id-attribute-cannot-be-accessed-in-linq-query-for-an-object-of-a-class-that-has-a-list-of?forum=csharpgeneral` can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Include()` on the navigation property, it will bring the entire inner object in the query result. It's only automatic if you filter or select items from the inner object, otherwise you have to manually request an include.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
var allProducts = _db.Products.Include(d => d.Producer).ToList();
```

Always go with `Include` instead of lazy loading if you're not sure.

Comment: how can i make the Producer appear in the datagridview? the dgv couldnt read it